# Get all lucene values that have a certain fieldName

Tags: c#, lucene

To solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618227/faster-way-to-get-distinct-values-from-lucene-query) problem I created a new Lucene index where all possible distincted values of each field are indexed seperatly.

So it's an index with a few thousand docs that have a single Term.
I want to extract all the values for a certain term. For example, I would like all values that have the fieldName "companyName".
Defining a WildcardQuery is off course not a solution. Neither is enumerating ALL fields and only saving the ones with the correct fieldName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (I take it it still is in C#)

```
IndexReader.Open(/* path to index */).Terms(new Term("companyName", String.Empty));
```

Comment: ah, empty string :)
(added C# tag)

Comment: I always missed that in Java. But I realize `String.MissingString` would have been appropriate. (Huh, good that java did not have this!)