# getting a specific field values from lucene

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

i just started learning how lucene works and am trying to implement it in a site i allready wrote with mysql.

i have a field named `city` in my documents, and i want to get all the values for city from the documents.

i have found this question ( which is exactly what i need ) [Get all lucene values that have a certain fieldName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619260/get-all-lucene-values-that-have-a-certain-fieldname)
but all they show there is a line of code, and as i said, i am not experienced enough to understand how to implement that.

can someone please help me with some code to implement `IndexReader.Open(directory,true).Terms(new Term("city", String.Empty));`

what comes before / after that declaration ?

i have tried this:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryPath = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("LuceneIndex"));
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(directoryPath);
    Lucene.Net.Index.TermEnum iReader = IndexReader.Open(directory,true).Terms(new Term("city", String.Empty));
```

but how do i iterate over the results?

Comment: See this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327375/find-all-available-values-for-a-field-in-lucene-net/7330670#7330670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop should iterate over all the terms:

```
Term curTerm = iReader.Term();
bool hasNext = true;
while (curTerm != null && hasNext)
{
    //do whatever you need with the current term....
    hasNext = iReader.Next();
    curTerm = iReader.Term();
}
```

Comment: even due this seems very logical, it got stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: But don't you need to check if you're running into another field with your iteration? Just curious: maybe it's different in lucene.net.

Comment: So why did you mark this as Accepted? Did you solve the infinite loop problem?

Comment: @L.B thanks, corrected the code. Took it from some official documentation though, so bit surprised why it lacked such important part..

Comment: Still, I think that you need a check for `curTerm.Field() != "city"` :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C# API, but it looks very similar to the Java one.

What this code does is to get an instance of `IndexReader` with read-only access that is used to read data from Lucene index segments stored in `directory`. Then it gets an enumeration of all terms, starting at the given one. Dictionary (index part that stores the terms) in Lucene is organized `.tis` files, ordered lexicographically first by field name and then by term text.

So this statement gives you an enumeration of all term texts, starting at the beginning of the field `city` (besides: in Java you would rather write `new Term("city")`). You now need to find out the C# API of this enumeration, and then walk through it till you will get a `Term` that have something different as the `field()`.

A final note: generally, you should avoid doing things like this: it may for example limit your ability to distribute the index. If it turns out that this is a thing that you are doing at the very beginning of using Lucene, then it's probable that you are using it more like a document database than a search library.

Comment: basicly i am using it as a document database, since its a lot faster then anyother DB i tried. i build a phonebook using lucene, and at some point i need to show only cities, thats why i followed that path.